# KML file in Google Earth shows name of entity replacement

Tags: kml, google-earth

I've got a question referring to the BalloonStyle Tutorial in the KML documentiation: 
[BalloonStyle Documentation](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/extendeddata#balloonStyle)

Playing around with this KML file:

```
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"> 
<Document>   
  <name>ExtendedData+SchemaData</name>   
  <open>1</open>    
  <!-- Create a balloon template referring to the user-defined type -->
  <Style id="trailhead-balloon-template">     
    <BalloonStyle>       
      <text>
        <![CDATA[         
          <h2>My favorite trails!</h2>         
          <br/><br/>         
          The $[TrailHeadType/TrailHeadName/displayName] is <i>$[TrailHeadType/TrailHeadName]</i>.        
          The trail is $[TrailHeadType/TrailLength] miles.         <br/>        
          The climb is $[TrailHeadType/ElevationGain] meters.         <br/><br/>       
        ]]>
      </text>     
    </BalloonStyle>
  </Style>     

  <!-- Declare the type "TrailHeadType" with 3 fields -->
  <Schema name="TrailHeadType" id="TrailHeadTypeId">     
    <SimpleField type="string" name="TrailHeadName">       
      <displayName><![CDATA[<b>Trail Head Name</b>]]></displayName>     
    </SimpleField>     
    <SimpleField type="double" name="TrailLength">       
      <displayName><![CDATA[<i>The length in miles</i>]]></displayName>     
    </SimpleField>     
    <SimpleField type="int" name="ElevationGain">       
      <displayName><![CDATA[<i>change in altitude</i>]]></displayName>     
    </SimpleField>   
  </Schema>       

  <!-- Instantiate some Placemarks extended with TrailHeadType fields -->    
  <Placemark>     
    <name>Easy trail</name>     
    <styleUrl>#trailhead-balloon-template</styleUrl>     
    <ExtendedData>       
      <SchemaData schemaUrl="#TrailHeadTypeId">        
        <SimpleData name="TrailHeadName">Pi in the sky</SimpleData>         
        <SimpleData name="TrailLength">3.14159</SimpleData>         
        <SimpleData name="ElevationGain">10</SimpleData>       
      </SchemaData>     
    </ExtendedData>     
    <Point>       
      <coordinates>-122.000,37.002</coordinates>     
    </Point>   
  </Placemark>    
  <Placemark>     
    <name>Difficult trail</name>     
    <styleUrl>#trailhead-balloon-template</styleUrl>     
    <ExtendedData>
      <SchemaData schemaUrl="#TrailHeadTypeId">         
        <SimpleData name="TrailHeadName">Mount Everest</SimpleData>        
        <SimpleData name="TrailLength">347.45</SimpleData>         
        <SimpleData name="ElevationGain">10000</SimpleData>       
      </SchemaData>    
    </ExtendedData>    
    <Point>       
      <coordinates>-121.998,37.0078</coordinates>     
    </Point>   
  </Placemark>   
</Document> 
</kml>
```

When you remove one of the SimpleData elements, Google Earth shows the Entity Replacement from the Balloon Template. For example you remove the line `<SimpleData name="ElevationGain">10000</SimpleData>`
it shows up in the Balloon like "The climb is $[TrailHeadType/ElevationGain] meters." Which doesn't look very nice.

Any idea how to tell Google Earth, that it shouldn't display the line from the balloon, if there is a missing SimpleData?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

*I don't think** you can do what you are asking here - i.e. apply conditional logic within this style text. I have had a similar requirement in the past (certain pieces of data were missing from some of my placemarks) and I ended up applying different styles for each of the possible scenarios of missing information when generating the KML.

It felt both very clunky and if you have a large number of scenarios of one or more items being missing while others exist it could quickly be a mess.

*Would love to be wrong.

**UPDATE**

Just looked at my code for this, and I actually ended up putting all the text in the placemark fields of my schema, and printing out empty nodes when I did not have data - also less elegant, but did not require additional styles in the end. Based on your example something like:

```
<BalloonStyle>       
  <text>
    <![CDATA[         
      <h2>My favorite trails!</h2>         
      $[TrailHeadType/TrailHeadName/displayName] 
      $[TrailHeadType/TrailLengthBalloonText]               
      $[TrailHeadType/ElevationGainBalloonText]              
    ]]>
  </text>     
</BalloonStyle>

<Placemark>     
 <name>Difficult trail</name>     
 <styleUrl>#trailhead-balloon-template</styleUrl>     
 <ExtendedData>
  <SchemaData schemaUrl="#TrailHeadTypeId">         
    <SimpleData name="TrailHeadName">Mount Everest</SimpleData>        
    <SimpleData name="TrailLength">347.45</SimpleData>         
    <SimpleData name="ElevationGain">10000</SimpleData> 

    <SimpleData name="TrailHeadNameBalloonText"><![CDATA[The trail name is Mount Everest</br>]]></SimpleData>        
    <SimpleData name="TrailLengthBalloonText"><![CDATA[The trail is 347.45 miles.</br>]]></SimpleData>         
    <SimpleData name="ElevationGainBalloonText"><![CDATA[The climb is 10000 meters.</br>]]></SimpleData> 
  </SchemaData>    
 </ExtendedData>    
 <Point>       
  <coordinates>-121.998,37.0078</coordinates>     
 </Point>   
</Placemark>
```

Then when you have no data you leave that item blank:

```
<Placemark>     
 <name>Difficult trail</name>     
 <styleUrl>#trailhead-balloon-template</styleUrl>     
 <ExtendedData>
  <SchemaData schemaUrl="#TrailHeadTypeId">         
    <SimpleData name="TrailHeadName">Mount Everest</SimpleData>        
    <SimpleData name="TrailLength">347.45</SimpleData>         
    <SimpleData name="ElevationGain">10000</SimpleData> 

    <SimpleData name="TrailHeadNameBalloonText"><![CDATA[The trail name is Mount Everest</br>]]></SimpleData>        
    <SimpleData name="TrailLengthBalloonText"></SimpleData>         
    <SimpleData name="ElevationGainBalloonText"></SimpleData> 
  </SchemaData>    
 </ExtendedData>    
 <Point>       
  <coordinates>-121.998,37.0078</coordinates>     
 </Point>   
</Placemark>
```

Answer (score 0):

As my data are changing somehow quite often, I'm now providing a xml file linked to an css file and embed it as an iframe in the description. For offline use, create a kmz and put the xml and css into it.

For a small tutorial have a look here: 
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_display.asp

In the kml, it looks as follows:

```
<description>
    <![CDATA[
        <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog_with_css.xml"></iframe>
    ]]>
</description>
```